# hector exploration with move base

Tags: ros, navigation, exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, there,

I am trying out hector exploration on my robot and I have a few questions regarding the configuration. I have used the explore package before and the result is ok. The hector exploration, on the other hand, appears better on paper (though not confirmed). My specific questions are:

In order to use hector exploration, another node need to call the service provided by the hector_exploration_node and feeds the provided goals to move_base. However, when I dig out the hector_exploration_node source code, I don't see a "goal" message published, instead it is the trajectory (hector navigation msg) message. How do I pass this trajectory msg to move base as a goal?  Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100136/hector-exploration-with-move-base/) by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I concede that integration with move_base wasn´t a top priority with hector_exploration. There currently is no code to directly write out a generated target pose, but you can just take the last pose in the generated [nav_msgs/Path](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html) message and forward that to move_base. The nice thing about the way hector_exploration works is that along with the generated exploration pose, it also produces a path to it. This is pretty hard to leverage with the way move_base works, however.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on 2013-11-12**:
Thanks Stefan. I also noticed that there is a hector_path_follower node in the package and it is used together with the navigation_experimental package. If I were to use these two, do I still need move_base?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-11-12**:
No, in that case, the robot can explore the environment without using move_base at all. This is mainly for demonstration though and does not have some of the advanced features of move_base (like avoidance of dynamic obstacles).

**Comment by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on 2014-10-27**:
Hello, I am to use the hector_exploration_node on ROS Hydro, with a Husky, but I don't succeed to compile the node and can't use it. Do you have any idea? Is it because of the ROS version? Thank you
http://answers.ros.org/question/195473/hector_navigation_node-problem-compilation/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've submitted a really simple script implementing what Stefan suggested.

https://github.com/RainCT/hector_navigation/blob/master/hector_exploration_node/move_base_controller.py

---

Originally posted by [Siegfried Gevatter](https://answers.ros.org/users/1599/siegfried-gevatter/) with karma: 119 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-11-21**:
Nice ;) I´ll look into merging that back ...probably after the DRC Trials in December.